# How to use multiple NER pipes with the same spaCy nlp object?

Tags: spacy, named-entity-recognition

I trained a custom NER model for specific entity types (say, DRUGS) that are different from those that come out of the box in the standard spaCy models (ORG, PERSON, etc.). Is it possible to add the NER pipe from this custom model to another model that already contains the standard spaCy NER pipe? I tried the following:

```py
import spacy

custom_nlp = spacy.load('my_trained_model/model-best/') #trained with the GPU option from the spaCy Quickstart page
doc = custom_nlp('Chantix is a drug')
print(doc.ents) # Prints Chantix as a DRUG, as expected

main_nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_trf')
doc = custom_nlp('Chantix is a drug')
print(doc.ents) # Prints Chantix as a PRODUCT, as expected

main_nlp.add_pipe('ner', source=custom_nlp, name='custom_ner', before='ner')
print(main_nlp.pipe_names) # Both custom_ner and ner are there in the expected order
doc = main_nlp('Chantix is a drug')
print(doc.ents) # Here hell breaks loose, basically any token becomes an entity
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your added `custom_ner` is listening to the `transformer` component from `en_core_web_trf` rather than the one from the `custom_nlp` pipeline, so it's not getting the right input and is producing nonsense.

You need to "replace the listeners" before you add the component to `en_core_web_trf`:

```py
custom_nlp.replace_listeners("transformer", "ner", ["model.tok2vec"])
main_nlp.add_pipe('ner', source=custom_nlp, name='custom_ner', before='ner')
```

Docs: https://spacy.io/api/language/#replace_listeners

Comment: That worked! However, initially, I thought it would be possible to avoid running two transformers, which makes the overall run twice as slow. Is it possible to train the `custom_nlp` such that it listens to the transformer in `en_core_web_trf`, or am I talking gibberish?

Comment: It would only work if you could also continue to the train the tagger and parser at the same time, so you'd need training data with annotation for all the components (tags and dependency parses). It only works well in practice if the `transformer` + all listening components are all trained at the same time on the same fully-annotated data.